# Two way communication between android and Server

Tags: android, web-services, sockets

i want a two communication between server and Android. From Android want to send my current location coordinates to server after each 10 minutes. i can send message or images to server at any time. Similarly from server i want to send data to Android whenever needed.

**What should be the architecture of my application.**

Communication from Android to server and Server to Android is independent of each other i should not ask it as a two way communication but infact  i want communication from both sides to each other any time.

**Should i use a Web service of any kind or just network sockets or Something else.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [websockets](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or...

Simply send data from phone to the server using normal request. When you want send something from server to telephone you can use push notifications ([C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)) and if you receive such push message you know that server has data for you and telephone can download it using normal request;-). It depends what data you want to send. Sometimes this approach will be good, sometimes it's better to use websockets, TCP sockets or even XMPP protocol ;-)

Comment: This mean Server cannot send data explicitly to Android rather it will ask the Android phone to come and get the Data from the Server?

Comment: Id you're using C2DM yes - server can only ask phone to come and get data from  the server.

If you will use sockets - you will be able to send data directly to Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Acknowledge for the same. You need to Implement ACK/NACK Logic in your code. When you are sending Data just wait for ACK for a particular time period. If ACK is not received the you need to send NACK for the same. Here you need to use a session-id ( a kind of id for communication at both side, which can be any random number ).

You can use this Logic at both the side.

Comment: like what you were expecting ?

Comment: i was requesting to suggest me an architecture of communication between Server and Android. Should i use Web service OR Sockets OR something else that let me transfer data between Android and a Server.

Comment: oh ok, sorry for my mis-understanding, you can use Web Services as per my Answer

Comment: why shouldn't i use Sockets instead of using Web Service. which one is fast because i want data transfer to be fast and moreover at a time many thousands of Clients will be connected to the same server. can u elaborate please.

Comment: well I have not used SocketConnection still , I use web services for sending receiving data. so i asked you for same