# Get android GPS location in my web appliaction

Tags: java, android, web-applications, spring-mvc

I have web application developed using java spring technology. Now I want to extend it to android devices which requires me to get the current location of the android devices. Can someone guide me on how to go forward on this?

As per my understanding the web application will have to send a notification to the android and then the android client will have to send a message to the web application with the lat and long information.

But how do I send notification to the android client here?

Comment: You can use Inbuilt GPS class in Android, please check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16371874/2310673) to get current lat and long of android device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) to send the request from server to android phone. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) link as well. Also, the answers to following questions may be helpful you: [Two way communication between android and Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390257/two-way-communication-between-android-and-server) and [Android: How to periodically send location to a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775628/android-how-to-periodically-send-location-to-a-server).